iDRAC stop executing some RACADM commands after a while
I'm using racadm raid get pdisks -o command to get server physical disk information and I noticed that this command is working after iDRAC(iDRAC9 Enterprise) reboot but stop working(racadm ERROR: Unable to perform requested operation) after some time(2-3 days). Other commands like racadm hwinventory are working. If I reboot iDRAC it's working again. This command is executed in our desktop .NET app and this app not always get data.
What could be the reason and possible fix? Thank you!
